# What is the equivalent C# REGEX matches function to vba macro?

Tags: c#, regex, vba

I have code here in c# and I want it to convert to vba macro but I can't find the Matches function on it. How can I convert this code to vba macro? here's my sample code:

```
String input1 = "CODE.0002 ,TESTING.0002  CODE.0001";
var m1 = Regex.Matches(input1, @"(CODE\.\d{0,5})");
var list = new List<string>();

foreach (Match match in m1)
{
   list.Add(match.Value);
}
```

Comment: Can you please also show the VBA code that you already have tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops